# how can i use setPreferredSize in java?

Tags: java, swing, program-entry-point

I have a problem: I want to create a small game, I have to make a window like the following:

[image]

When I tried to change the font size of "Fun With Words", it wasn't changed ...

What should I do?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.JComponent;



public class GameWords extends JFrame 

{
    private static int W = 800 ;
    private static int H = 600 ;



    public GameWords ()
    {
         setTitle ( " Word Order Game " ) ;
         setSize ( H , W ) ;
         setLayout ( new FlowLayout() ) ;
         setDefaultCloseOperation ( EXIT_ON_CLOSE ) ;
         createContent () ;
         setVisible ( true ) ;
    }

    public void createContent ()
    {
        JLabel heading = new JLabel (" Fun With Words ") ;
        heading.setFont ( heading.getFont().deriveFont ( 26f ) );
        heading.setPreferredSize ( new Dimension ( H , 4 * W ) ) ;
        JLabel h1 = new JLabel ( " Hey Kids! Want to prictice your typing and word-ordering Skills ? \n" ) ;
        add ( heading ) ;
        add ( h1 ) ;


    }


    public static void main(String[] args) 

    {
        new GameWords () ;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is don't, the API is quite capable of calculating the desired size it self.

The longer answers is, don't use `setSize`, use `pack` instead, which uses the containers preferred size to calculate the size of the window

```
public GameWords ()
{
     setTitle ( " Word Order Game " ) ;
     setLayout ( new FlowLayout() ) ;
     setDefaultCloseOperation ( EXIT_ON_CLOSE ) ;
     createContent () ;
     pack();
     setVisible ( true ) ;
}

public void createContent ()
{
    JLabel heading = new JLabel (" Fun With Words ") ;
    heading.setFont ( heading.getFont().deriveFont ( 26f ) );
    JLabel h1 = new JLabel ( " Hey Kids! Want to prictice your typing and word-ordering Skills ? \n" ) ;
    add ( heading ) ;
    add ( h1 ) ;


}
```

As a general recommendation, you shouldn't extend directly from a `JFrame`, you're not adding any new functionality to the class and you're locking yourself into a single use case. As a general recommendation, you should start by extending from `JPanel` and then add this to whatever container you want to use

Comment: Great , it's working now .. but can you tell me why it's working when we use pack ? because my doctor well ask me , thanks for my help ^_^

Comment: When you call pack() on a JFrame, the JFrame asks its children (recursively) what their preferred sizes are, and since you are specifying a FlowLayout, the JFrame lays out its children left-to right at their prefered size. But you should heed  the advice of @MadProgrammer and not subclass from JFrame unless you are overriding one of its methods. In your case, you don't even need to subclass JPanel, since you are not adding any functionality to it either. Just create a JPanel that contains the JLabel, then create a JFrame and add the panel to it.

Comment: @Mj___3 As fred has said, `pack` will "pack" the frame around the contents, based on the contents preferred size.  This information is calculated by the various layout managers been used